# Use Dynamo (Visual Programming Language) as Orchestrator in Event Based System

Tags: events, workflow

My team is creating an event based factory integration system using Kafka. We are evaluating whether we can use Dynamo as orchestratoror workflow engine for following requirement:

When consumer A receive msg A from topic A then:

1. Consumer A trigger workflow A (a Dynamo script) and pass msg A to workflow A
2. 1st node of workflow A forward msg A to topic B
3. Service B (subscribed to topic B) receives msg A as input and start calculation, then return msg B (consisting calculation result) to 1st workflow node
4. 1st workflow node pass msg B to 2nd node
5. 2nd node evaluate data in msg B, and pass msg B to node 3A if certain condition is met, otherwise pass msg B to node 3B.
6. Node 3A and 3B forward msg B to different services if they are triggered.

I understand these requirements can easily be done using NService Bus or Mass Transit, but customer requires the system to show orchestration workflow in visual form instead of code. May I know can these requirements be achieved using Dynamo with custom nodes? If not, is there any open source technology/visual programming tool that you believe can be used for this task?

Thank you.

According to informatin gathered, python script and c# code can be executed as custom nodes in Dynamo, but it seems the application of Dynamo is limited to AEC industry, and I am not sure wheter custom nodes can be used to send and receive reply from other services. Any suggestion/thought is appreciated. Thanks.